# Single Logout with One Login PHP and ADFS

Tags: php, laravel, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs

I'm building a web app based on Laravel framework and I need to add support for SSO using ADFS as the Identity Provider.

I was able to enable Single Sign On using the [package laravel-saml2](https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2) that is based on [onelogin toolkit](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml) but now I'm stuck with Single Logout.

When the LogoutRequest is made from the web application, the following error is shown in the ADFS error logs.

> Microsoft.IdentityServer.RequestFailedException: MSIS7054: The SAML
>   logout did not complete properly.
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The parameter is
>   incorrect. at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32
>   hr) at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.DecryptKey(SafeKeyHandle
>   pKeyContext, Byte[] pbEncryptedKey, Int32 cbEncryptedKey, Boolean
>   fOAEP, ObjectHandleOnStack ohRetDecryptedKey) at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(Byte[]
>   rgb, Boolean fOAEP) at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeDeformatter.DecryptKeyExchange(Byte[]
>   rgbIn) at
>   System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenResolver.SimpleTokenResolver.TryResolveSecurityKeyCore(SecurityKeyIdentifierClause
>   keyIdentifierClause, SecurityKey& key) at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.CreatePlaintextReaderFromEncryptedData(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, SecurityTokenResolver serviceTokenResolver,
>   SecurityTokenSerializer keyInfoSerializer, Collection`1 clauses,
>   EncryptingCredentials& encryptingCredentials) at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ReadEncryptedId(XmlReader
>   reader) at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Saml2AssertionSerializer.ReadEncryptedId(XmlReader
>   reader) at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SingleLogoutService.ProcessMessage(SamlMessage
>   samlMessage, BindingInformation bindingInformation, Boolean
>   partialLogout, Boolean validResponseMessage, Boolean&
>   validLogoutRequest) at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolManager.Logout(HttpSamlMessage
>   logoutMessage, String sessionState, String logoutState, Boolean
>   partialLogout, Boolean isUrlTranslationNeeded, HttpSamlMessage&
>   newLogoutMessage, String& newSessionState, String& newLogoutState,
>   Boolean& validLogoutRequest)

Below is listed the onelogin settings I am using.

```
<?php

//This is variable is an example - Just make sure that the urls in the 'idp' config are ok.
$idp_hostname = 'login.adfs.pt';

return $settings = array(
    /*****
     * Cosmetic settings - controller routes
     **/
    'useRoutes' => true, //include library routes and controllers


    'routesPrefix' => '/saml2',

    /**
     * Where to redirect after logout
     */
    'logoutRoute' => '/',

    /**
     * Where to redirect after login if no other option was provided
     */
    'loginRoute' => '/',


    /**
     * Where to redirect after login if no other option was provided
     */
    'errorRoute' => '/',




    /*****
     * One Loign Settings
     */



    // If 'strict' is True, then the PHP Toolkit will reject unsigned
    // or unencrypted messages if it expects them signed or encrypted
    // Also will reject the messages if not strictly follow the SAML
    // standard: Destination, NameId, Conditions ... are validated too.
    'strict' => true, //@todo: make this depend on laravel config

    // Enable debug mode (to print errors)
    'debug' => true, //@todo: make this depend on laravel config

    // Service Provider Data that we are deploying
    'sp' => array(

        // Specifies constraints on the name identifier to be used to
        // represent the requested subject.
        // Take a look on lib/Saml2/Constants.php to see the NameIdFormat supported
        'NameIDFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified',

        // Usually x509cert and privateKey of the SP are provided by files placed at
        // the certs folder. But we can also provide them with the following parameters
        'x509cert' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX MY SP Public key XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'privateKey' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXYXX My SP Private key YXYYYYYYYYYYYYYY',

        //LARAVEL - You don't need to change anything else on the sp
        // Identifier of the SP entity  (must be a URI)
        'entityId' => '', //LARAVEL: This would be set to saml_metadata route
        // Specifies info about where and how the <AuthnResponse> message MUST be
        // returned to the requester, in this case our SP.
        'assertionConsumerService' => array(
            // URL Location where the <Response> from the IdP will be returned
            'url' => '', //LARAVEL: This would be set to saml_acs route
            // SAML protocol binding to be used when returning the <Response>
            // message.  Onelogin Toolkit supports for this endpoint the
            // HTTP-Redirect binding only
            //'binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
        ),
        // Specifies info about where and how the <Logout Response> message MUST be
        // returned to the requester, in this case our SP.
        'singleLogoutService' => array(
            // URL Location where the <Response> from the IdP will be returned
            'url' => '', //LARAVEL: This would be set to saml_sls route
            // SAML protocol binding to be used when returning the <Response>
            // message.  Onelogin Toolkit supports for this endpoint the
            // HTTP-Redirect binding only
            //'binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
        ),
    ),

    // Identity Provider Data that we want connect with our SP
    'idp' => array(
        // Identifier of the IdP entity  (must be a URI)
        'entityId' => 'http://' . $idp_hostname . '/adfs/services/trust',
        // SSO endpoint info of the IdP. (Authentication Request protocol)
        'singleSignOnService' => array(
            // URL Target of the IdP where the SP will send the Authentication Request Message
            'url' => 'https://' . $idp_hostname . '/adfs/ls/',
            // SAML protocol binding to be used when returning the <Response>
            // message.  Onelogin Toolkit supports for this endpoint the
            // HTTP-POST binding only
            'binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
        ),
        // SLO endpoint info of the IdP.
        'singleLogoutService' => array(
            // URL Location of the IdP where the SP will send the SLO Request
            //'url' => $idp_host . '/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php',
            'url' => 'https://' . $idp_hostname . '/adfs/ls/',
            // SAML protocol binding to be used when returning the <Response>
            // message.  Onelogin Toolkit supports for this endpoint the
            // HTTP-Redirect binding only
            'binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
        ),
        // Public x509 certificate of the IdP
        'x509cert' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ADFS Identity Provider public key  XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        /*
         *  Instead of use the whole x509cert you can use a fingerprint
         *  (openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -in "idp.crt" to generate it)
         */
        //'certFingerprint' => '',

    ),



    /***
     *
     *  OneLogin advanced settings
     *
     *
     */
    // Security settings
    'security' => array(

        /** signatures and encryptions offered */

        // Indicates that the nameID of the <samlp:logoutRequest> sent by this SP
        // will be encrypted.
        'nameIdEncrypted' => true,

        // Indicates whether the <samlp:AuthnRequest> messages sent by this SP
        // will be signed.              [The Metadata of the SP will offer this info]
        'authnRequestsSigned' => true,

        // Indicates whether the <samlp:logoutRequest> messages sent by this SP
        // will be signed.
        'logoutRequestSigned' => true,

        // Indicates whether the <samlp:logoutResponse> messages sent by this SP
        // will be signed.
        'logoutResponseSigned' => true,

        /* Sign the Metadata
         False || True (use sp certs) || array (
                                                    keyFileName => 'metadata.key',
                                                    certFileName => 'metadata.crt'
                                                )
        */
        'signMetadata' => false,


        /** signatures and encryptions required **/

        // Indicates a requirement for the <samlp:Response>, <samlp:LogoutRequest> and
        // <samlp:LogoutResponse> elements received by this SP to be signed.
        'wantMessagesSigned' => false,

        // Indicates a requirement for the <saml:Assertion> elements received by
        // this SP to be signed.        [The Metadata of the SP will offer this info]
        'wantAssertionsSigned' => false,

        // Indicates a requirement for the NameID received by
        // this SP to be encrypted.
        'wantNameIdEncrypted' => false,

        // Authentication context.
        // Set to false and no AuthContext will be sent in the AuthNRequest,
        // Set true or don't present thi parameter and you will get an AuthContext 'exact' 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport'
        // Set an array with the possible auth context values: array ('urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password', 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:X509'),
        'requestedAuthnContext' => false,
    ),

    // Contact information template, it is recommended to suply a technical and support contacts
    'contactPerson' => array(
        'technical' => array(
            'givenName' => 'name',
            'emailAddress' => 'my@email.pt'
        ),
        'support' => array(
            'givenName' => 'Support',
            'emailAddress' => 'my@email.pt'
        ),
    ),

    // Organization information template, the info in en_US lang is recomended, add more if required
    'organization' => array(
        'en-US' => array(
            'name' => 'Michael',
            'displayname' => 'Michael',
            'url' => ''
        ),
    ),

/* Interoperable SAML 2.0 Web Browser SSO Profile [saml2int]   http://saml2int.org/profile/current

   'authnRequestsSigned' => false,    // SP SHOULD NOT sign the <samlp:AuthnRequest>,
                                      // MUST NOT assume that the IdP validates the sign
   'wantAssertionsSigned' => true,
   'wantAssertionsEncrypted' => true, // MUST be enabled if SSL/HTTPs is disabled
   'wantNameIdEncrypted' => false,
*/

);
```

I've been searching about this error for a while but I was not able to find any help on how to solve it. Am I missing some configuration ?

Comment: Can you provide a SAML Logout example?. Also I recommend to set false the nameIdEncrypted parameter

Comment: Well I was enable to by pass this issue, by using the following logout url:
'url' => 'https://' . $idp_hostname . '/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0',
The LogoutRequest is now made to ADFS but I get the following error on the aplication side:
Signature validation failed. Logout Request rejected

Comment: You can found the LogoutRequest that is sent, here
http://pastebin.com/bYGGpw5B

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also set to false the nameIdEncrypted parameter

Comment: There is a new version of the toolkit, try it

Comment: Did you ever figure out an answer to this? I'm in the same situation.

Comment: Unfortunately not.